# Process hour in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a stored procedure, I need to do a calculation based on a difference between 2 dates. To make the difference I use `datediff(hour, @startDate, @endDate)`. But, depending on the hour, I need to add or not 1.

For exemple, If `@startDate = '2020-09-16 05:00` and `@endDate = '2020-09-16 08:00`, I will only use `datediff(hour, @startDate, @endDate)`. But, if `@startDate = '2020-09-16 05:00` and `@endDate = '2020-09-16 08:01`, I need to do `datediff(hour, @startDate, @endDate)+1`.

The problem is that I don't know how to process the "rounded hour".

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in a table format* would help.

Comment: "depending on the hour, I need to add or not 1." - can you be more *specific* about what the logic is here. All you've done is given us two samples and said "I do for this, I don't for that". How do *you* (and thus, we, and eventually a computer) distinguish these two examples?

Comment: It isn't very clear what you mean, as has been commented. But I suspect your problem could be solved by calculating the difference in minutes, and getting hours from that.

Comment: `ceiling(datediff(minute, @sdate, @edate)/ 60.0)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could test to see if the 'minutes' part of the endDate is greater than 0.

```
declare
  @startDate      datetime='2020-09-16 05:00',
  @endDate        datetime='2020-09-16 08:01';

select datediff(hour, @startDate, @endDate)+
       case when (datepart(minute, cast(@endDate as time))>0) then 1 else 0 end;
```

Output

```
4
```

Comment: Thank you @SteveC, it's exactly what I need !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to add 1 hour if the second date is greater than 8AM, you can make a little logical process by just comparing this difference and put into DATEADD function, with previous use of CAST function, for example:

```
DECLARE @DATE1 DATETIME = '2020-09-16 05:00'
       ,@DATE2 DATETIME = '2020-09-16 08:01'

IF CAST(DATEDIFF(s, @DATE1, @DATE2) AS DECIMAL (9,3)) / 3600 > 3
BEGIN  
    SELECT 1 --Here replace this expression with your ADD logical part.
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 0
END
```